# 'Darkened' textures while moving camera in 3D games

Tags: graphics-card, display, gaming

I've tried a lot of things, but I'm really at the end of my rope. I wanna fix this issue, which I have in multiple games, usually in darker scenes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9GJ.jpg

I've tried all sorts of settings on my monitor (Samsung 27LG50, a 27" VA), only reducing the sharpness to ridiculous levels really helps. I've tried all sorts of settings in the game. Even with everything at the lowest, the effect occurs. I did check out my driver's settings (Gigabyte 1080 Ti Aorus), but I can't find any candidates there. Is there no fix for this? Every topic I find on this issue doesn't include any real solutions so far. Only disabling TraceFree on an Asus monitor for some guy (but I've got a Samsung).

If not, I'd like to just know what causes it, and buy me a monitor which doesn't do this. Thanks in advance. :(

Comment: Could this be caused by temporal antialiasing? If you recorded this using software on your machine then it it unlikely to be a monitor issue.

Comment: @Mokubai Recorded it via my smartphone (the first video), because it shows best that way. Good test though. This happens when I record it via Nvidia's recording option: imgur.com/a/wSZMA1K What's weird is that it does show the effect when viewing the video in VLC on my PC. It disappears on Imgur and on my phone. So ... Monitor issue?

Comment: That video doesn't show the effect to me so it sounds like a monitor issue, most likely your monitor suffers from particularly bad ghosting and poor grey to grey (g2g) transition and what you are seeing is the motion of the darker areas. Playing the video in VLC would be the same as in game, playing it on another (better) device is best to see whether the monitor or graphics are at issue. I have an old Samsung which did something similar but nowhere near as bad. There might be a "response time" setting in your monitor. I can recommend Samsungs QLED 144Hz gaming range monitors...

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for your quick replies, man. Here is the file without compression. It shows the effect heavily in VLC for me. https://gofile.io/?c=zfJDXP Could you check this one out as well?

Comment: I don't see the effect at all in that last video, at least not what is clearly obvious in your first video, where the roof area literally goes darker while the camera is panning. It does seem that this is an effect of a slow panel or one which is trying to do some ugly motion compensation. Does your monitor have a "gaming" mode? Some do and it does a lot to try and reduce the ghosting effect and disabling a lot of image processing. I cannot find your monitor model online to see how old it is or what it has.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, @Mokubai! It's this one: https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1239897/samsung-lc27jg50qqu-zilver/specificaties/ Already fiddled around with A LOT of the settings, including response time and sharpness. Only thing that really 'fixes' it, is jamming sharpness to 0 ...

Comment: If that is your monitor then [your manual](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_UK&CttFileID=7357481&CDCttType=UM&ModelType=N&ModelName=C27JG50QQU&VPath=UM/201906/20190619124343444/BN46-00712A-Eng_for_India.pdf&OriginYN=N) looks like you might have both "Eco saver" and "Eye saver" modes which could both do extra processing and have weird backlight effects and would be worth disabling, otherwise there might also be some game modes that might improve things. Specifically enabling low input latency and anything to reduce processing and "smart" features.

Comment: @Mokubai Everything is off, and I left the response time at 'faster' after resetting, left low input log on, and put the refresh rate down to 60, because the effect gets definitely worse at 144. I'm kinda out of ideas, haha.

Comment: I did turn up sharpness to 80 instead of 60 now (due to blurry text), and turned the brightness down to 20 (I sit in a dark-ish room). I also set color temp to gamma mode 3 (looks way better). These settings don't seem to have a real effect, only sharpness.

Comment: What about the "game mode" settings? The manual claims that FPS mode will increase the brightness of darker areas and could have some effect. I'm a bit at a loss as well, it shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: @Mokubai It does get less noticeable then, but I can still change all options 'back'. The main difference I think is that the black level option is set to 8 instead of 13 and brightness is cranked up to 100. The brighter, the better, it also seems. Don't know if I find that FPS option viable, because changing the brightness back to 20 makes everything the same mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that some games, especially the not very recent ones, have this problem above 60 fps, so if you have for example an NVIDIA card (I think it also applies to AMD) I suggest you limit the maximum fps for that game to 60.